# Javascript modal window routine executes more time with each click

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

So I have a modal dialog window which you are able to pass functions into.

```
function dialog(message, yesCallback, noCallback) {

    $('#modal_dialog div.title').html(message);
    var dialog = $('#modal_dialog');
    dialog.show();

    $('#btnYes').click(function() {
        yesCallback();
        setTimeout(function(){dialog.hide();},3000);
    });
    $('#btnNo').click(function() {
        noCallback();
        setTimeout(function(){dialog.hide();},3000);
    });
}
```

When I pass functions into it using:

```
$(document).on('tap','.rsvp',function(event){
  console.log('rsvp');
  value = $(this).parent().find('.storyid').text();
  dialog($(this).parent().find('H4').text(),function(){doingComing(value,'yes');},function(){doingComing(value,'no');});
});
```

It works the first time find.... fires once...
when I go to click the .rsvp class again and then click the yes or no button it fires two times.

then three times

then four times.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is being bound every single time the `dialog` method is invoked. As jQuery allows multiple events of the same kind to be attached to an element.

One way of approaching this is binding and unbinding of events when the `dialog` method is called. This is more of a hacky approach as constant binding and unbinding is considered an anti pattern.

The second approach would be is to move the click events to outside of the `dialog` method and find a way to differentiate between the callbacks.